# How does one upload a synthesized solution to the Arduino Vidor FPGA?

Tags: programming

I've compiled a solution and have received a ttf file from Intel Quartus which is designed for the Vidor 4000 Arduino board. The file represents a synthesized bitstream to be sent to the FPGA. How do I upload the file to the FPGA onboard the VIDOR board? I've got a JTAG programmer if necessary.